# after cancel method tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.5

I have been through many examples about after cancel method in `Tkinter`but I am not clear about that.In my code I am using the after method to enter the value of `s` in entry box after a certain time delay.Now i need to stop that after the cycle is completed when a button is pressed.

```
def read_pressure():
    global s
    s+=1
    E3.delete(0,'end')
    E3.insert(0,s)
    top.after(1000, lambda:read_pressure())
```

Now i need to stop these loop using a button.How to do that??
I am using python 3.5
 With the help of Dan  i can able to stop after method.But it freezes my gui and I can't able to recall the after method.
How to do that?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the return value around:

```
handle = top.after(1000, lambda:read_pressure())
```

And then when the button is clicked do:

```
if handle:
   top.after_cancel(handle)
   handle = None
```

Both with `global handle`. I would prefer to make these methods and use self to store state than mutate globals.

Comment: yes,this one pause the after loop. But, when i try to resume after loop gui gets freezed. How to overcome this one

Comment: How do you resume it?

Comment: Again I will call the function with the button